# How to rename pandas column names by splitting with space

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe like this:

```
index   col A   col B   col C
index1    3       1       2
index2    1       4       9
index3    5       1       2
index4    8       2       2
index5    2       1       6
```

I want to rename columns by splitting them with space. I dont want to do it manually since I have hundreds of columns. My ouutput looks like this:

```
index     A       B       C
index1    3       1       2
index2    1       4       9
index3    5       1       2
index4    8       2       2
index5    2       1       6
```

Can anyone help me with this

Comment: Would this do the trick? `df.columns = df.columns.str.split().str[1]`

Comment: Do you always have **one** space? Is it always "col"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split().str[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you have multiple prefixed words to ignore:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split()[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the last word:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.extract(r'(\S+)$', expand=False)
```

Output:

```
    index  A  B  C
0  index1  3  1  2
1  index2  1  4  9
2  index3  5  1  2
3  index4  8  2  2
4  index5  2  1  6
```